# Where is class Ord defined in GHC library?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Source for [`GHC.Base`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html) has the note at the beginning saying in part

```
The overall structure of the GHC Prelude is a bit tricky...
So the rough structure is as follows, in (linearised) dependency order


GHC.Prim        Has no implementation.  It defines built-in things, and
                by importing it you bring them into scope.
                The source file is GHC.Prim.hi-boot, which is just
                copied to make GHC.Prim.hi

GHC.Base        Classes: Eq, Ord, Functor, Monad
                Types:   list, (), Int, Bool, Ordering, Char, String
```

But while `Ordering` is defined in that source file, `Ord` isn't. And the Prelude doc page doesn't have a source link for `Ord`. Where is it actually defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ord` (and `Eq`) are defined in the [`GHC.Classes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim) module (which is imported by `GHC.Base`) from the [*ghc-prim*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.1.1/src/GHC/Classes.hs) package (which is a dependency of *base*).